# Can't get return key to move text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Hello i am making an app that uses a login page and registration page. I need to make it so when in the login page for example, i can press the return key (customised to say next) and it will move the cursor to the next text field. I have researched it a lot and have found some code that should work however no matter what i do it won't work.

Code 1 -

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == field1TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [field2TextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
    else if (textField == field2TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [field3TextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == field3TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This makes sense to me however it wont work.

My first text field is called txtUsername and my second text field is called txtPassword. So i customized the code like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == txtUsername) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

I have setup a custom .h & .m file and am placing the code in there. Should i be linking the code to the text field somehow?

Comment: Your issue is likely related to those custom files... Why don't you move that code to your login view controller?

Comment: Can you post your custom .h/.m files ?

Comment: Several things to check: are txtUserName and txtPassword properly set?  is your viewController (I assume) set as the delegate for the text fields?  textFieldShouldReturn should be returning NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call the `textFieldShouldReturn` method you will need to set the delegate of the UITextField. In your `viewDidLoad` method, add:

```
txtUsername.delegate = self;
txtPassword.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thank you so much that has worked. Really appreciate the help and quick response.

Comment: I am glad I helped. Please consider accepting my answer if you find it useful. :)